# How to avoid ECS Spot instance termination while processing user requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, spot-instances

I'm planning to run an ECS cluster with an ALB in front of spot instances.
As an example: A user's request enters a container that is running on spot, but before getting the response, the spot instance is terminated. That will return an error, right?

How can I resolve this type of issue?

Is there any way to stop sending requests before it was gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable something called as `ECS_ENABLE_SPOT_INSTANCE_DRAINING`, it will change the instance to draining state and no *new* requests would come to this instance. The time frame is 2 minutes, if your requests will be longer then the user would get error.

- [Developer Guide: Using Spot Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-spot.html)
- [AWS Blog: Best practices for handling EC2 Spot Instance interruptions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-handling-ec2-spot-instance-interruptions/) -
  Check the "Inside a Container Running on Amazon ECS" section